# how to write a python code for the cost of an item and the change due in British money

Tags: python

I'm in a python class and know very little about Python. I'm having trouble with something and am trying to figure this stuff out.  Note that I am **not asking for code solutions**. I am merely looking for feedback and help.

The part I am stuck on is I don't know how to make a code that puts in the total cost of a purchase, and the amount paid.

I am stuck with the last part of this assignment :

> Listing 3.4 of the textbook:
>   ComputeChange.py, accepts a dollar and cents amount of money and outputs a multiset (a set that can contain more than one copy of an element) of coins consisting of pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, and Sacagawea dollars with minimal cardinality. Your mission is to modify this program as follows:
>     1) Your program must input two numbers: the total cost of a purchase and the amount of money paid. Both inputs are in British pounds with two decimal places.
>     2) Outputs the multiset of coins with minimal cardinality that is equal in value to the change due using the eight dominations pictured above. Note: in the modern British system, 1 pound equals 100 pence.
>     3) Outputs the results in the format specified below.
>
> Your total change is: £□□□□.□□
>
> Where:
>     a) The empty boxes above are replaced by the digits (or spaces) of the correct total change due.
>     b) The digits >1 are right justified within a field of 4 spaces.
>     c) Exactly two digits after the decimal place must be displayed, even if zeros.

OK, so in my textbook I have written the textbook code, but substituted dollars, dimes, quarters and nickels, for their British money equivalents. Here is my code so far:

```
#9/11/2013
#The Pound Is Sinking

# Receive the amount
amount = float(input("Enter the amount"))

# convert the amount to pence
remainingamount = int(amount * 100)

# find the number of two pounds
numberOfTwoPounds = remainingAmount // 200
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 200

# find the number of one pound
numberOfOnePounds = remainingAmount // 100
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 100

# find the number of fifty pence
numberOfFiftyPence = remainingAmount // 50
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 50

# find the number of twenty pence
numberOfTwentyPence = remainingAmount // 20
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 20

# find the number of ten pence
numberOfTenPence = remainingAmount // 10
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 10

# find the number of five pence
numberOfFivePence = remainingAmount // 5
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 5

# find the number of two pence in the remaining amount
numberOfTwoPence = remainingAmount // 2
remainingAmount = remainingAmount % 2
```

Comment: I can't figure out what your question is. " I don't know how to make a code that puts in the total cost of a purchase, and the amount paid." does not mean anything to me.

Comment: I would perhaps address why your TA isn't willing to assist you - I would have thought it would be their job - not that of the SO community to help you do this assignment!

Comment: I think he's just asking for some code that will accept a couple of numbers from the keyboard.

Comment: "I don't know how to make a code that puts in the total cost of a purchase" - Yes you do: `amount = float(input("Enter the amount"))`

Answer (score 4):

Here is another suggestion. Unlike many computer languages, python can help you write your program.

To start, type "python" or "python3", depending upon which version you want to use. You will then see a message telling you what version you are using and ">>>". Every time you get one of those ">>>" prompts, you can type something. So after you enter

```
>>> amount = float(input("Enter the amount: "))
Enter the amount: 14
>>> amount
14.0
>>>
```

So you see that you can experiment and learn how things work. For example, you could enter "1R" instead of "14". People with fat fingers might do that, you know.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '1R'
>>>
```

So basically, you can "single step" your way through, keeping track of what works and what doesn't, putting what works into the program that you are writing.

Answer (score 3):

Here is another hint that you will find helpful if you follow it. You will often be given a problem for which you will need to write a program. Don't start writing the program to solve the problem. Many people - even very experienced programmers work that way. That is the slowest way to solve your problem.

Instead, take just one small part of the problem, and solve that. For example, you need two numbers, before you can make change. But that is still not a problem to solve. The first problem to solve is getting ONE number input. If you can solve that simple problem, you can reuse the solution, with a minor change to solve the other half of the larger problem.

Next you would worry about making change. But don't glue the inputs in just yet. Just start with the amount paid, and the cost and fix them at some known value. At this point you will realize the the amount paid has to be more than the cost, or else you will be making negative change! If you don't realize it, then you will see some surprising results, often known as bugs.

Continue solving the small problems. Then just "glue" them all together in some way that is easy to follow.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Your code looks good, you are just missing the second input and the output:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

total = float (input ('Total amount: £') )
paid = float (input ('Cash received: £') )
change = int (paid * 100 - total * 100)

multiset = []
for nomination in [200, 100, 50, 20, 10, 5, 2, 1]:
    count = change // nomination
    change = change % nomination
    for _ in range (count): multiset.append (nomination)

print (', '.join ('{:.2f}'.format (nomination / 100) for nomination in multiset) )
print ('Total change: £{:>4.2f}'.format (paid - total) )
```